# different output when runing the same script in Selenium

Tags: selenium

The same scripts occasionally give me some `exception (NoSuchElementException)` 
or

`ElementClickInterceptedException)` while running fine most of the time. What could be the cause?

```
public static void yesNoDropDown(WebElement x, WebElement y){
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(x));

    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    actions.moveToElement(element).click().perform();

    WebElement element2 = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(y));

    element2.click();
```

Comment: not enough info here, but seems like it would be due to timeouts (10 seconds up before expected condition is met).  The click intercepted exception will tell you what element is causing that particular exception...  In general when a bug is seemingly random it's usually due to a timing issue or memory leak.

Comment: Do you see `NoSuchElementException` and `ElementClickInterceptedException` for the same element or different elements?

Comment: How are you determining WebElement x and y? Are you using PageFactory?
Instead, try to pass By variable here, wait for them and click.

Comment: First element usually gets ElementClickInterceptedExeption and the second one - NoSuchElementExeption. I do use PageFactory, but have tried to pass veritable directly - same output.